# Changing $scope.variable in $scope.$on function does not update view

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angular-ui-router

I want to listen for route changes and update a $scope variable to reflect the current route in my menu (md-nav-bar):

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {
    $scope.currentNavItem = $location.path();
    console.log('current location path', $scope.currentNavItem);
});
```

The output is correct (e.g. '/overview'), however, the view/menu is not updated. Do I need to initiate the update manually?

Comment: there isn't enough info here to know why your view isn't being updated.  In order to troubleshoot this kind of issue, the *entire* controller definition and the view need to be listed, at a minimum.

Comment: Can you try using $scope.$apply(); after $scope.currentNavItem = $location.path(); statement?

Comment: @Claies The controller is quite long, I will see what I can do, perhaps a jsFiddle.

Comment: @PaulsonPeter I tried that, but then this error comes up (3x): `angular.js:13920 Error: [$rootScope:inprog] $digest already in progress`

Comment: if not the entire controller, at least the pertinent parts, which include the module name, where these particular properties are initially created, and where they are consumed.  It's ok to omit other properties that aren't relevant to the problem.  You might read through how to create a [mcve] for more information on what I am suggesting.

Answer (score 5):

If you change a scope variable in an event function (setTimeOut, $scope.$on...etc.), you have to manually call `$scope.$apply()` for the variable to be updated in the scope.

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {
    $scope.currentNavItem = $location.path();
    $scope.$apply();
});
```

If this somehow results in an [error "digest already in progress"](https://docs.angularjs.org/error/$rootScope/inprog#common-causes) you can wrap a timeout function around the code setting your variable:

```
$scope.$on('$routeChangeSuccess', function(event, current) {
  $timeout(function() {
    $scope.currentNavItem = $location.path();
  })
}
```

However, scope/rootScope events should not be used for minor variable updates. It's not scalable and you will end up with tonns of event listeners everywhere.

In this particular case you should use the tools at your disposal in ui-router:

- ui-sref
- ui-sref-active

You probably already use `ui-sref` to navigate between states:

```
<a ui-sref="state1">state1</a>
<a ui-sref="state2">state2</a>
```

With ui-router you can also use the `ui-sref-active` directive that will add a class to your link if the states correspond.

```
<a ui-sref="state1" ui-sref-active="active">state1</a>
<a ui-sref="state2" ui-sref-active="active">state2</a>
```

When clicked on state1 the following html is generated:

```
<a ui-sref="state1" ui-sref-active="active" class="active">state1</a>
<a ui-sref="state2" ui-sref-active="active" class="">state2</a>
```

You can then style the active class however you please.

Comment: I tried using `$timeout`, which works, but I agree it's not beautiful. So I adapted `ui-sref` (it's called `md-nav-sref` according to the documentation) but this also does not work. I have: `<md-nav-bar md-selected-nav-item="currentNavItem"> <md-nav-item name="overview" md-nav-sref="overview" ui-sref-active="active">Overview</md-nav-item>` I tried `/overview` as well, but with no effect. It does not even switch routes anymore. I wish the documentation would have some real-world examples or provide better info.